# setupbld.exe created setup.exe that does not uninstall application

Tags: wix, installation

How to prepare setup.exe with setupbld.exe (I packe msi) that can install and uninstall application. Currently I can install application but when I run installer second time it does not show Change / remove options but precede directly to window with install button. When I run msiexec /i myApp.msi then I can install and later change /remove.

I use following path to pack my msi

```
setupbld.exe -out c:\Setup.exe -mpsu c:\outTEst\a.msi -setup setup.exe -title "setup"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old setupbld is just a simple bootstrapper; it doesn't support chainer features like maintenance mode. If you want that, check out Burn in WiX v3.6.